# Pandas DataFrame Resample to OHLC : How to set last close value as next open?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a resampled OHLC dataframe whose sample looks below:

```
                           open        high         low       close
Timestamp                                                          
2021-08-15 12:45:00  234.546533  234.546533  234.468163  234.468163
2021-08-15 13:00:00  236.484534  236.809475  235.186271  236.718901
2021-08-15 13:15:00  236.888803  237.276931  235.456240  235.456240
2021-08-15 13:30:00  235.334325  237.199735  233.155842  233.875636
2021-08-15 13:45:00  234.046381  234.949318  232.092734  234.276051
```

But the dataframe row `open` is actually inaccurate.

For example, close value of 1st row (`234.468163`) should be open value of 2nd row.

However, it's (`236.484534`) instead of (`234.468163`).

This makes the plot of chart quite incorrect.

**Here's what I tried after searching a lot:**

`df['open'] = df['close'].shift()`

Ofcourse, it fixes almost everything, but just shows `NaN` for first Row.

```
                           open        high         low       close
Timestamp                                                          
2021-08-15 12:45:00         NaN  234.546533  234.468163  234.468163
2021-08-15 13:00:00  234.468163  236.809475  235.186271  236.718901
2021-08-15 13:15:00  236.718901  237.276931  235.456240  235.456240
2021-08-15 13:30:00  235.456240  237.199735  233.155842  233.875636
2021-08-15 13:45:00  233.875636  234.949318  232.092734  234.276051
```

How can I fix this `NaN` to it's original value i.e. (`234.546533`).
Since this dataframe gets generated using API, I shouldn't be setting it manually, but it should rather done automatically.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic way is to use `.fillna()` which fills in `NaN` values, since you only have one:

```
df['open'] = df['close'].shift().fillna(df['open'])
```

Here we’re using the open values to fill in the series.

Comment: Actually, for doing this.. I would to set it myself. This data gets generated using API. How can it be done automatically?

Comment: I really apologise. I have made edits in my question.